# Why is std::isnan not constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

As of C++20 std::isnan is not constexpr.

Is there a technical reason for this?

All I can think of is that it is in "C header" so nobody bothered to fix it (`<limits>` functions dealing with floats are constexpr, but unfortunately `numeric_limits` does not contain isnan check).

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't originally made constexpr because checking for NaN usually requires punning and bit twiddling of the sort that is disallowed in constant expressions. But then again, compilers are allowed to "magically" make stuff constexpr when needed. So, I can only guess.

Comment: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0533r5.pdf
Maybe we'll get it in C++23

Comment: Could it be something in `std::fpclassify` that prohibits it right now?

Comment: `x!=x` is your friend.

Comment: NoSesseEtAll: Doesn't the answer you've gotten answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is basically "Because the proposal hasn't been merged into the standard yet"

[P0533](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0533r6.pdf) Proposes what you are asking, and it did not make it into C++20.

One of the holdups is that perhaps this proposal is a little big... some of the functions in `<cmath>` or `<cstdlib>` are allowed to set global error codes, which complicates the whole "`constexpr` all the things" proposal<sup>*</sup>

I don't think there should be any issue with these classification functions; `std::isnan` and its sibling `std::fpclassify` are defined to behave identically to the C macros `isnan` and `fpclassify` respectively. This will need to change slightly.

---

<sup>*</sup>(aside: [p2043](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2043r0.pdf) "Don't `constexpr` all the things" is tangentially relevant here, but it's only talking about metaprogramming)